# Database relation concept

Tags: mysql, database-design, entity-relationship

Good morning, experts

I need your advice. Let's say we have `user`, `profile` and `post` entities.

Variant 1: `user` has many `profile`, `profile` has many `post`

Variant 2: `user` has many `profile`, `user` has many `post`

What's the best? By convenience, "right way", or maybe even performance?

Comment: Can you explain what the `user`, `profile` and `post` actually represent?  What are you actually going to do with the data, how frequently and on what scale?

Comment: @Surreal Dreams, thanks for reply. They actually represent what they are :) `Post` data is the most frequent in creating/updating, then users and profiles.

Sure, on the current stage a project is not big enough. But in the future I expect 10K views a day.

Comment: What is the difference between a `User` and a `Profile`? Why does a user have many profiles?

Comment: @wuputah, best example - stackexchange. In SO - one profile, in superuser - another one, with different data in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends...

1) on how the system works..if the posts are associated with profiles. Then you should use Variant 1. For example, the questions I post in Stackoverflow should be associated with my Stackoverflow profile. The questions I post in Superuser should be associated with that profile.

If you want to maintain this type of behaviour with Variant 2. The post would have to have a field indicating where the post belongs.

2) on how you will use the data. If you do not need the profile information when querying for posts, then may be you shouldn't associate profile and post.

3) In terms of performance, using very basic logic, joining across 3 tables to retrieve some information is likely to be worse than joining across 2 tables (of course depends on the columns in the join, index etc...but say all else being equal).

I think the best thing to do is to keep it simple. Keeping it simple, it'll be easier to figure out if something will work the way you expect it to. If it doesn't, it will be easier to figure out why and fix it. And if required, it'll be easier for you to modify it later on as well.

Comment: Thanks for clear reply. Gonna keep it simple and then optimize.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean to ask:  "In general, when designing a data model, what considerations should be valued highest - convenience, correctness, or performance?",  then I would say that correctness should be a first priority. Convenience and performance will be secondary concerns.

Comment: I assume that it can be correct, but too slow. Ok, thank you, hash1baby.

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 seems much better to me.
But specifying what kind of information your store in a profile would help understanding.
I assumed that profile holds role/category information.

Comment: thanks. Profiles keep specific information, in example, local reputation or smth like this (in terms of StackExchange).